# chrome extension background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm unable to call my jQuery hide body in a page content with a custom chrome extension.

background.js

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {

    // The srcUrl property is only available for image elements.
    //var url = 'info.html#' + info.srcUrl;

    // Create a new window to the info page.
    //alert(info.srcUrl);

    //chrome.windows.create({ url: url, width: 520, height: 660 });
  };
};



window.addEventListener("load", initialize);



function initialize(){
    if(jQuery){
        alert('yes');
    }else{
        alert('no');
    }
    jQuery('body').hide();
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Get image info",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["image"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

manifest.js

```
{
  "name" : "Imageinfo",
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "description" : "Get image info for images, including EXIF data",
  "background" : { "scripts": ["jQuery.js", "background.js"] },
  "permissions" : [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
   ],
  "minimum_chrome_version" : "6.0.0.0",
  "icons" : {
    "16" : "imageinfo-16.png",
    "48" : "imageinfo-48.png",
    "128" : "imageinfo-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I just want to hide the body in this exemple. I do get the 'Yes' alert but nothing after that. Maybe I miss something with manifest 2. I try some example but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your manifest is correct?

Try correcting your manifest to match this

```
{
  "name" : "Imageinfo",
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "description" : "Get image info for images, including EXIF data",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "icons" : {
  "16" : "imageinfo-16.png",
  "48" : "imageinfo-48.png",
  "128" : "imageinfo-128.png"
},


  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "permissions": [ 
  "contextMenus",
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*"
 ],
 "web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery.js"
  ],
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You will need to create a background.html page which will have the following in its `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```